# How to deploy "extension method" within a VSIX extension?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, vsix

Due to the wording (many meanings of "extension" and "method"), I am utterly unable to find **any** information about my question on the interwebs. So I am asking here:

Is it possible to deploy "extension methods" with a VSIX extension?

Clarification:
By "extension method" I mean something like

```
public static string SomextExtension(this string s, string p) {
   retrun s + p;
}
```

By VSIX extension I refer to a custom extension, that gets installed via a

> SomeCoolExtension.vsix

The goal is:
A user installs the VSIX, gets a few features (mainly custom code generators in my case) and additionally has access to `"Hello".SomeExtension(" World");` within their source code.

I am slowly thinking this just isn't possible as I have tried everything I could come up with and as stated in the beginning, it is virtually impossible to search for it on googls.

If it really is impossible, I would at least love to understand why.
So a simple "no" might be a valid answer, but if you could elaborate, that would put my coding soul to rest :-)

Specs: I am using VS2017 and the new "Visual Studio AsyncPackage", but if you know an answer for older version, I sould be happy to try them.

Comment: A vsix package offers features to the IDE (shortcuts, refactorings, snippets) but not code. To make code available you need a Dll containing that code that can be referenced by the project. Vsix extensions just don't work like that. You might also be able to add a snippet that actually inserts the extension method's code into a project. Otherwise you need a dll/nuget package that can be installed/referenced.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As this question was viewed more than twice (you & me ;-)), I think you should post this as an answer that I can accept. It might spare someone hours of searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both approaches:

- An extension (.vsix) provides the greatest flexibility, because it can provide commands (buttons on menus, context menus and toolbars) that, on demand by the user, can 1) Insert code in the active document 2) Add files with code or other assets 3) Add references to Dlls that the extension can deploy in the source folder of the project, etc. Also, it can do all that not only on demand, but automatically watching events and examining if some conditions are met, for example, a solution is created, or it is loaded, a project is added, it already contains a code file or not, it already has a reference or not, etc. Needless to say, all this flexibility comes from some complexity.
- A NuGet package can add DLLs to the references or code files to a project, it can execute a PowerShell script when the NuGet package is added to a project that can modify the project, it can modify the build process adding new MSBuild targets/tasks (being the Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools NuGet package to create a VSIX extension the prime example). It is a one-time operation during installation on a project. After that, no events, no commands, etc. but for most scenarios is much simpler.

Comment: Wow! First of all thank you for the thorough answer. Could you elaborate just a tiny bit on 3) Add references to Dlls that the extension[...].

Comment: See my sample https://github.com/visualstudioextensibility/VSX-Samples/tree/master/VSIXDebuggerVisualizer to show how a VSIX can include a Dll as payload and deploy it to some folder. The sample is about a debugger visualizer but it could be a Dll that you add as reference to a project using EnvDTE.Project.Object-> VSLangProj.VSProject and then VSLangProj.VSProject.References.Add(pathToAssemblyDll)